# How To add Product Detail page in Add an Extra box and Receive 10% off the Total Button

Tags: woocommerce

Product Detail page add extra button  in this button click redirect homepage also product add into the cart  used variable and variation

Answer (score 1):

Use 'woocommerce discount rules plugin' for this. You can create new discount rule in this plugin. And this is also display notice meessage on cart page when rule applied